# Mailing multiple files from inbound file connector in a single mail

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I can't seem to figure out how I can achieve the following:

1) Mule needs to pick up files from a directory and put it on an ftp (this part is working)

2) Next, it needs to mail the files that were uploaded in a single mail, with the body of the mail mentioning the filenames of the files that were uploaded.

=> This second part I don't understand how to do this using mule blocks. I tried using different property scopes for saving my filenames in a list, but every time I get to the aggregator block all my properties are gone (including the session ones). The files are aggregated though, but I need the filenames also.

Am I missing something obvious here? thanks!

Here's my xml:

```
<flow name="KCM-FTP" doc:name="KCM-FTP"> 
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="${path.kcm.uploadfolder}"></file:inbound-endpoint>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="1"/>
        <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="100"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="${ftp.host}" port="${ftp.port}" path="${path.ftp.inputfolder}" user="${ftp.username}" password="${ftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"></ftp:outbound-endpoint>  
    <collection-aggregator timeout="15000" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"></collection-aggregator>  
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties"> 
        <add-message-property key="EmailHeader" value="#['KCM uploader \n Run: ' +server.dateTime + '\n\nFiles uploaded:\n']"></add-message-property>  
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <set-attachment attachmentName="test" value="#[payload]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Attachment"/>
    </foreach>

    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" to="${mail.to}" subject="${mail.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" from="${mail.from}"></smtp:outbound-endpoint>  
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself by implementing a small java class. Apparently the message properties weren't lost, you just couldn't see them in the debugger anymore because the debugger only shows the properties of the messageCollection that comes out of the aggregator.

My flow only needs to run 1 time / hour + the amount of files does not exceed 100/hour , hence my simple aggregator which just times out after 1 minute to decide there's no more files to process.

Flow xml:

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="KCM-FTP" doc:name="KCM-FTP"> 
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="${path.kcm.uploadfolder}" ></file:inbound-endpoint>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Set Aggregation Properties">
        <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="1"/>
        <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="100"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="${ftp.host}" port="${ftp.port}" path="${path.ftp.inputfolder}" user="${ftp.username}" password="${ftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"/>
    <collection-aggregator timeout="15000" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Set Email Header">
        <add-message-property key="EmailHeader" value="#['KCM uploader \n Run: ' +server.dateTime + '\n\nFiles uploaded:\n']"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <custom-transformer class="com.company.kcm.Transformer.FileParser" doc:name="Add mail attachments"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" to="${mail.to}" from="${mail.from}"  subject="${mail.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>

</flow>
```

Java transformer implementation:

```
public class FileParser extends AbstractMessageTransformer implements Transformer {

private String body;

@Override   
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage src, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {        

    try {

        if(src instanceof MuleMessageCollection) {
            MuleMessageCollection messageCollection = (MuleMessageCollection)src;

            MuleMessage[] messagesAsArray = messageCollection.getMessagesAsArray();
            body = messageCollection.getOutboundProperty("EmailHeader").toString();

            //Add all input files as email attachments
            for (MuleMessage muleMessage : messagesAsArray) {

                messageCollection.addOutboundAttachment((String) muleMessage.getInboundProperty("originalFilename"), muleMessage.getPayload(),"text/plain");

                body += (String) muleMessage.getInboundProperty("originalFilename") + "\n";
            }

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return body;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Your flow will run one time for each of the files the file inbound endpoint finds. You won't be able to send all the files together in the same email unless you store them in an other place. But... how would you know that you finish reading all files? When should you start executing your flow? You can trigger a flow with an HTTP listener and then pick up all the available files using a Java component.